# Problema al subir multiples imagenes Axios Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

estoy intentando subir y guardar multiples imagenes con Axios y una API en Laravel, pero al hacerlo me da error 422, hasta el momento por lo que he logrado entender, el problema esta en la API que no procesa los datos que vienen de Axios (perdon soy novato), si alguien me puediera orientar o ayudarme en que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias de antemano (=

```
///Axios

    async submitFiles(){
       let fd = new FormData()
       for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
         let file = this.files[i]
         fd.append('photo[' + i + ']', file)
       }
       try{
        await this.$axios.$post(`/albums/${this.$route.params.id}/photos`, fd, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
        console.log(...fd)
        alert('uploaded')
        this.files = []
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        alert(err)
      }

     }
```

Controlador Laravel

```
//Laravel

class PhotosInAlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function store(PhotoInAlbumRequest $request, Album $album)
    {


        if($request->hasfile('photo')) 
        {

            $photo = new PhotoInAlbum();
            $photo->photo = $request->photo;
            $images[] = $request->file('photo');
            foreach ($images as $image) 
            {
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = pathInfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $path = $image->storeAs('photo/images', $filenameToStore,'public');
                $photo->photo = $path;
                $album->photos()->save($photo);

            }

        }

        return $photo;

    }
}
```

Comment: No se si estás usando axios desde el `app.js` que viene con Laravel, sino asegurante des estar enviando el header de [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, la solucion fue mover estas 2 lineas dentro del Foreach =D

```
$photo = new PhotoInAlbum();
$photo->photo = $request->photo;
```